# jQuery AJAX call doesn't execute success block

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Javascript function that does an ajax REST call to a spring controller to grab some stuff from a database and plot it on a map. For some reason the success area of the ajax call isn't executing, but the GET request is returning with a status of 'success'. Is there any reason why my success block wouldn't execute but the complete block would?

query:

```
$j.ajax({
        url:         url,
        type:      'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        sucess:   function(json) {
            console.log("getTestData successful");
            boxes = parseJsonForTestData(json);
            //console.log(">> boxes = '" + boxes + "' <<");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("getTestData failed with textStatus '" + textStatus + "' errorThrown '" + errorThrown + "'");
        },
        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
            console.log("getTestData complete textStatus='" + textStatus + "'");

            if( boxes.length != 0) {
                $j('#results_textfield').text(boxes.length + ' results found');
            }
            else {
                $j('#results_textfield').text(boxes.length + ' result found');
            }
        }
});
```

parseJsonForTestData:

```
function parseJsonForTestData(json) {
    console.log(">> In music.js function parseJsonForTestData <<");
    //...abstracted 
}
```

log:

```
AJAX call to api/rest/da/getTestData/ music.js (line 310)
GET http://localhost:8080/s2i/api/rest/da/getTestData/

200 OK  39ms    jquery-latest.js (line 6054)

getTestData complete textStatus='success'
```

Note that none of the console.log statements from the success block or parseJsonForTestData appear in the log file.

Any ideas or advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have written  `sucess:` instead of `success:`

that's why the code is not executed (and maybe you should have some related error in js console)

Comment: Cant believe I missed that, I also would have expected an error but I don't get anything in Firebug. I will accept as soon as it is up, thanks.

Comment: The reason you don't get an error is because JS simply believes you are creating a member of your JSON with the name 'sucess'.  It is created and your function is assigned to it, but because it is not named 'success', it is never called by jQuery's AJAX framework.

Comment: @GaryK Thank you for the explanation, that makes more sense to me